Run-time error 432 when running VBA script
I am trying to run a VBA script in Autocad and I get the following error: "Automation Error - element not found" Clicking on Debug highlights this line:
Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")
I can see that the file is present in the folder.
Public acad As Object
Public acadapp As AcadApplication, AcadDoc As AcadDocument
Public doc As Object
Public ms As Object
Public ss As Object
Public ssnew As Object
Public ssnew2 As Object
Public Theatts As Variant
Public Theatts2 As Variant
Public MsgBoxResp As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim BlkG(0) As Integer
Dim ro As Integer
Dim TheBlock(0) As Variant
Dim Pt1(0 To 2) As Double
Dim Pt2(0 To 2) As Double
Dim insertionPnt(0 To 2) As Double
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
'Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")
Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06MX-SV.xlsx")
Set xlSheet = xlbook.Sheets("04-LB-06 MX")
Set xlapp = xlbook.Parent
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False

'set reference to workbook

ro = 2
'declare local variables

 Dim dwgName As String
 Dim vtag As String
 'vtag = "c:\07509\" & sh.Cells(ro, 5) & ".dwg"
 Debug.Print vtag
 
testflZS
 
xlbook.Close savechanges:=False
'save the changes in Excel

xlapp.Quit
'quit Excel
 
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set axlapp = Nothing
'clean up

ThisDrawing.Save
ThisDrawing.Close
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim BlkG(0) As Integer
Dim ro As Integer
Dim ssnew As Object
Dim TheBlock(0) As Variant
Dim Pt1(0 To 2) As Double
Dim Pt2(0 To 2) As Double
Dim insertionPnt(0 To 2) As Double
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")
Set xlSheet = xlbook.Sheets("04-LB-06 MX")
Set xlapp = xlbook.Parent
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
'set reference to workbook

I tried to run the script and I expected it to generate some Autocad drawings.

You have two lines for the Set xlbook, I imagine because that space you already tested for as the cause?

You may also want to try declaring it as a different data type such as just a Workbook

What happens if you use Set xlApp = New Excel.Application, then Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")?

Try debug.print Dir("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx") and see what it prints.

Yes I thought the space may be causing a problem.

@BigBen When I change the "Set xlapp" and "Set xlbook" lines, I get a run-time error 91 and it stops at the "Set xlsheet" line. Should I also change this?

After doing a repair installation of "Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise", I no longer have the error.
